# Flutter just_audio can't load audio asset on android builds

Tags: android, flutter, mp3, assets, just-audio

```
 void initState() { 
_myAudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setAsset("electric.mp3");
super.initState();}
```

Here is my code and here is the pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/electric.mp3
```

It can load the file on the web builds like Chrome but I both tried emulator and a real phone (both APIs are 33). It just saying:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8300): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 8300):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/flutter ( 8260): 
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled 
Exception: Unable to load asset: "electric.mp3".
E/flutter ( 8260): The asset does not exist or has empty data.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the pubspec.yaml file, THIS:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/electric.mp3
```

TO THIS:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And I was deleting the "/" too before. So the main solution is having the "/" at the end of the folder name. I didn't know this and because Chrome accepts it.

Answer (score 1):

you are not informing the correct path to the file, try this:

```
initState() { 
  _myAudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setAsset("assets/electric.mp3");
 super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Now it's not even building. Says: "No file or variants found for asset: assets".

Comment: Could you check the location of the file, if it is in the correct folder?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like incorrect path. You have added the path in pubspec.yaml as

`- assets/electric.mp3`.

Assuming you have added the mp3 in the assets folder.
So use the same path in the code.

```
   void initState() { 
    _myAudioPlayer = AudioPlayer()..setAsset("assets/electric.mp3");
    super.initState();
    }
```

Comment: Now it's not even building. Says: "No file or variants found for asset: assets".

Comment: Share the implementation code. Which plugin or native library you are using for the audio player?

Comment: Also check the project root folder and make sure you have a folder named 'assets' having the mp3. run flutter clean from terminal and re-run.